# Random Exception - "Service timed out: Spreadsheets" in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Apps Script that works fine for most (>95%) of the time.

- The script is bound to a Google Form and is set to be run on the 'On
  Form Submit' event.
- The script has a try-catch block.
- This block catches an exception once in a while - Service timed out:
  Spreadsheets.
- There is no pattern to when this occurs. It is random.

Just to clarify. The script DOES NOT time out and IT DOES finish running as expected.

But, on random occasions, the script does not do it's job because of the "Service timed out: Spreadsheets" exception that is thrown when the script tries to write to a Google Spreadsheet.

Is there any way I can figure out what's the root cause of this? And is there anyway I can get some support for this issue?

I tried contacting Google Workspace support and they directed me here to SO to see if I can get some help.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the sheet, and the code you are using to write to the Sheet?

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely hitting one of the [limitations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations) of Apps Script. Perhaps you should time the function and try to optimize your code.